# Volume UI Should not appear when using on screen volume slider- iOS

Tags: user-interface, ios10, avaudioplayer, mpvolumeview

[image]

Volume UI should not appear during use of volume slider of the application.

Answer (score 2):

I am not saying this is the perfect solution but somehow with this tricks, my problem has fled away:

```
 MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, -100, 0, 0)];
[self.view addSubview: volumeView];
```

I have implemented above code in viewWillAppear and problem resolved.
With above code you can also customise your volume controller frame.